# Why is it by design that MySQL closes the connection when max_packet_size is exceeded? Evidence based opinions acceptable as Answer

Tags: mysql

I have numerous WordPress websites that crash at random due to max_packet_size being exceeded by a request.

I have just increased the size, to hopefully avoid this in the future, but I don't understand why MySQL would intentionally severe a connection for a request that was too large instead of rejecting it.

This results in these websites going down. And I'm not confident that increasing the max_packet_size really solves the root problem which is the shutting down.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/packet-too-large.html

Does anyone have any insight as to why this occurs? Is my perspective on this issue lacking?

Comment: We can't answer questions about the design decisions made by third-party software developers.

Comment: That's not correct. There are members of MySQL that are on StackOverlfow and make contributions. Either way, I'm looking for evidence to explain the logic or maybe explain to me how my perspective is wrong and I need to think about it differently.

Comment: Most likely because it's something that's difficult to recover from and continue using the connection, since it's detected part-way through sending the results.

Comment: seems like the root problem is either way too low a setting or non-reasonably constrained queries?  unless you are doing something quite wrong you shouldn't be encountering this.